# Can't get to wrap text around and image & sliding overlay not working too

Tags: css, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/zoomit.js" async></script>
    <title>WebDev Profile</title>

    <style >

      body {
        background-color: lightsalmon;
        margin: 25px;}

      div.polaroid {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow:  0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        margin-right: 25px;
        width: 37.05%;
      }

      .polaroid:hover .overlay {
        height: 100%;
      }

     .text {
      white-space: nowrap;
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     }

     .overlay {
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-color: #008CBA;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: auto;
      height: 0;
      transition: .5s ease;
      }

      div.container {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        width: auto;
      }

      details {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 1.50em;
        font: "Times New Roman";
        font-style: italic;
      }
      .image {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background: black;
        display: block;
      }

      img:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
        -webkit-filter: blur(15px); /* Safari */
        filter: blur(15px);

      }

      h2 {
        color: white;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h2>Hilary Duff</h2>
    <div class="polaroid">
      <img src="hilary_duff_high.jfif" alt="Dushyant Kaushik" class ="image">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Hilary Duff, Adult</div>
        </div>
      <div class="container">
        <p>Hilary Duff, Adult</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- the other half -->


  <p class="details">INTJ (Introversion, Intuition, Thinking, Judgment) is an abbreviation used in the publications of the Myers–Briggs Type Indicator (MBTI) to refer to one of the 16 psychological types.[1]
According to Myers–Briggs the INTJ represents "The Mastermind". INTJs are one of the rarest of the 16 psychological types and account for approximately 2%[2] of the population.[3] Women of this personality type are especially rare, forming just 0.8% of the population.
The MBTI assessment was developed from the work of prominent psychiatrist Carl G. Jung in his book Psychological Types. Jung proposed a psychological typology based on the theories of cognitive functions that he developed through his clinical observations.
From Jung's work, others developed psychological typologies. Jungian personality assessments include the MBTI instrument, developed by Isabel Briggs Myers and Katharine Cook Briggs, and the Keirsey Temperament Sorter, developed by David Keirsey. Keirsey referred to INTJs as Masterminds,[4] one of the four types belonging to the temperament he called the Rationals.[5]
</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

[source file for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFfUv.jpg)

There is an image around which I want to wrap text enclosed in the paragraph tags. Also sliding overlay not coming while I take my pointer over the image. Can't figure out where I did wrong. Please all of you help me solve this problem.

Here is another image of how my page appears.
[Page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ImoB.png)

Comment: Not sure what your requirement is. Can you please write it a little better or show it with some example?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this solves it but from what I get is your text is not overlapping the image. That is because your details class doesn't have "." in front of it. It should defined as .details not details in css.

```
 .details {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 1.50em;
        font: "Times New Roman";
        font-style: italic;
      }
```

Link for your reference:
https://codepen.io/Harsh89/pen/OombZL

Comment: Thaks for your response mate. Sorry, but I removed details class and did all the styling straight to the p tag in <style> inside head.Now styling works good but but text by default hides behind the image, but when give position other than stati(absolute, relateive) , it comes to forward but overlap the image. That is what I don't want. Any suggestions further?

Comment: you don't want to overlap the image and keep the back in the background? Can you specify what is your exact requirement?

Answer (score 0):

1. You just replace position absolut in the polaroid div with float left to wrap.
2. That your hover is working you need to use max-height and transition: max-height. Also u need an invisible pseudo div with postion: absolute to hold on the place where u hover.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/zoomit.js" async></script>
    <title>WebDev Profile</title>

    <style >

      body {
        background-color: lightsalmon;
        margin: 25px;}

      .polaroid {
  position: relative;
        float: left;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow:  0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        margin-right: 25px;
        width: 37.05%;
      }

      .polaroid:hover .overlay {
        max-height: 100%;
      }
   
   .polaroid:hover .text {
        display: block;
      }

     .text {
      white-space: nowrap;
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      position: absolute;
   display: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     }
  
  .overlay {
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   -webkit-transition: max-height 1s; 
   -moz-transition: max-height 1s; 
   -ms-transition: max-height 1s; 
   -o-transition: max-height 1s; 
   transition: max-height 1s;  
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   max-height: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #008CBA;
   z-index: 999;
 }
 
 .overlay-pseudo {
  position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   max-height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 999;
 }

      div.container {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        width: auto;
      }

      .details {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 1.50em;
        font: "Times New Roman";
        font-style: italic;
      }
      .image {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background: black;
        display: block;
      }

      

      h2 {
        color: white;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h2>Hilary Duff</h2>
    <div class="polaroid">
      <img src="hilary_duff_high.jpg" alt="Dushyant Kaushik" class ="image">
  <div class="overlay-pseudo">
          
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">Hilary Duff, Adult</div>
        </div>
      <div class="container">
        <p>Hilary Duff, Adult</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- the other half -->


  <p class="details">INTJ (Introversion, Intuition, Thinking, Judgment) is an abbreviation used in the publications of the Myers–Briggs Type Indicator (MBTI) to refer to one of the 16 psychological types.[1]
According to Myers–Briggs the INTJ represents "The Mastermind". INTJs are one of the rarest of the 16 psychological types and account for approximately 2%[2] of the population.[3] Women of this personality type are especially rare, forming just 0.8% of the population.
The MBTI assessment was developed from the work of prominent psychiatrist Carl G. Jung in his book Psychological Types. Jung proposed a psychological typology based on the theories of cognitive functions that he developed through his clinical observations.
From Jung's work, others developed psychological typologies. Jungian personality assessments include the MBTI instrument, developed by Isabel Briggs Myers and Katharine Cook Briggs, and the Keirsey Temperament Sorter, developed by David Keirsey. Keirsey referred to INTJs as Masterminds,[4] one of the four types belonging to the temperament he called the Rationals.[5]
</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Daniel I think it will work. I will post again after trying it out.

Comment: Ok, if it works for you, please dont forget to mark question as answered. Thank you.